# Prometheus metrics are showing zero values for OpenEBS volumes?

Tags: monitoring, openebs

I’m getting zeros for 2 prometheus metrics: **openebs_total_write_bytes** & **openebs_total_read_bytes**. At the same time **openebs_write_block_count** is monotonically growing. OpenEBS v 0.8.

```
I1212 09:43:39.559667       1 jivacollector.go:59] Got response: {"Name":"pvc-2b15924e-fd57-11e8-b27a-42010a3f0103","ReadIOPS":"10","ReplicaCounter":3,"Replicas":[{"Address":"tcp://10.128.32.25:9502","Mode":"RW"},{"Address":"tcp://10.128.30.4:9502","Mode":"RW"},{"Address":"tcp://10.128.26.21:9502","Mode":"RW"}],"RevisionCounter":13168,"SCSIIOCount":{"40":10,"42":4113},"SectorSize":"4096","Size":"107374182400","Status":"RW","TotalReadBlockCount":"143360","TotalReadTime":"12792647","TotalWriteBlockCount":"40534016","TotalWriteTime":"68922008511","UpTime":"29594.443906","UsedBlocks":"613624","UsedLogicalBlocks":"613615","WriteIOPS":"4113","actions":{},"links":{"self":"http://127.0.0.1:9501/v1/stats"},"type":"stats"}
I1212 09:43:40.421493       1 jivacollector.go:59] Got response: {"Name":"pvc-2b15924e-fd57-11e8-b27a-42010a3f0103","ReadIOPS":"10","ReplicaCounter":3,"Replicas":[{"Address":"tcp://10.128.32.25:9502","Mode":"RW"},{"Address":"tcp://10.128.30.4:9502","Mode":"RW"},{"Address":"tcp://10.128.26.21:9502","Mode":"RW"}],"RevisionCounter":13168,"SCSIIOCount":{"40":10,"42":4113},"SectorSize":"4096","Size":"107374182400","Status":"RW","TotalReadBlockCount":"143360","TotalReadTime":"12792647","TotalWriteBlockCount":"40534016","TotalWriteTime":"68922008511","UpTime":"29595.305764","UsedBlocks":"613624","UsedLogicalBlocks":"613615","WriteIOPS":"4113","actions":{},"links":{"self":"http://127.0.0.1:9501/v1/stats"},"type":"stats"}
I1212 09:44:09.558113       1 jivacollector.go:59] Got response: {"Name":"pvc-2b15924e-fd57-11e8-b27a-42010a3f0103","ReadIOPS":"10","ReplicaCounter":3,"Replicas":[{"Address":"tcp://10.128.32.25:9502","Mode":"RW"},{"Address":"tcp://10.128.30.4:9502","Mode":"RW"},{"Address":"tcp://10.128.26.21:9502","Mode":"RW"}],"RevisionCounter":13174,"SCSIIOCount":{"40":10,"42":4119},"SectorSize":"4096","Size":"107374182400","Status":"RW","TotalReadBlockCount":"143360","TotalReadTime":"12792647","TotalWriteBlockCount":"40583168","TotalWriteTime":"68927678351","UpTime":"29624.442425","UsedBlocks":"613624","UsedLogicalBlocks":"613615","WriteIOPS":"4119","actions":{},"links":{"self":"http://127.0.0.1:9501/v1/stats"},"type":"stats"}
I1212 09:44:10.417433       1 jivacollector.go:59] Got response: {"Name":"pvc-2b15924e-fd57-11e8-b27a-42010a3f0103","ReadIOPS":"10","ReplicaCounter":3,"Replicas":[{"Address":"tcp://10.128.32.25:9502","Mode":"RW"},{"Address":"tcp://10.128.30.4:9502","Mode":"RW"},{"Address":"tcp://10.128.26.21:9502","Mode":"RW"}],"RevisionCounter":13174,"SCSIIOCount":{"40":10,"42":4119},"SectorSize":"4096","Size":"107374182400","Status":"RW","TotalReadBlockCount":"143360","TotalReadTime":"12792647","TotalWriteBlockCount":"40583168","TotalWriteTime":"68927678351","UpTime":"29625.301859","UsedBlocks":"613624","UsedLogicalBlocks":"613615","WriteIOPS":"4119","actions":{},"links":{"self":"http://127.0.0.1:9501/v1/stats"},"type":"stats"}
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenEBS has two storage engines currently supported,

- cStor (Recommended)
- Jiva

openebs_total_read_bytes and openebs_total_write_bytes are very specific cstor, it's not been implemented in jiva yet. Looks like you are using Jiva from the description, I would recommend you to use cStor which is the recommended Storage Engine by OpenEBS team.